# beautifulsoup with bscscan api in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to use beautifulsoup with the bscscan api but I don't know how to separate the data that someone gives me, could someone guide me?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url_base = 'https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=stats&action=tokensupply&contractaddress='
contract = '0x6053b8FC837Dc98C54F7692606d632AC5e760488'
url_fin = '&apikey=YourApiKeyToken'
url = url_base+contract+url_fin
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
totalsupply = soup.find('p').text
print(totalsupply)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please show result.

Comment: ready I just added it as an image

Comment: I think, the image shows dictionary data.
Try this.
status = totalsupply['status']
print(status)

Comment: If `{"status":"1","message":"OK","result":"1289436"}` isn't your desired output, can you tell us what your desired output is so we can help you? What do you want `totalsupply` to be?

Comment: @bituniverse it's an api I don't have access to the dictionary it's a string with that structure inside a link

Comment: @onlyphantom I want to separate those 3 things and save them in different variables

Comment: Got it @teco. What about `totalsupply`? What is your expected value for `totalsupply`?

Comment: @onlyphantom It was only to visualize the result of the code because the idea is to divide the "totalsupply" result into 3 pieces and save each one in corresponding variables

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and additional info. I've posted an answer for you with all the information you've given.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first part of the solution is almost identical to what you already have. Since you didn't need `pandas`, I've removed it. I've also changed the parser from `lxml` to `html`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url_base = 'https://api.bscscan.com/api?module=stats&action=tokensupply&contractaddress='
contract = '0x6053b8FC837Dc98C54F7692606d632AC5e760488'
url_fin = '&apikey=YourApiKeyToken'
url = url_base+contract+url_fin

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html')
```

By now, if you print `soup` you will see something like this:

```
{"status":"1","message":"OK","result":"1289436"}
```

You may think that's a python dictionary, but that's only the representation (`__repr__` or `__str__`). You still can't extract the keys and values as you would with a normal dictionary. `soup` is an instance of `bs4.BeautifulSoup`. So convert that into a json and then save each of the three items as its own variable:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import json

d = json.loads(soup.get_text())
status, message, result = itemgetter('status', 'message', 'result')(d)
```

Now you will have `status`, `message`, and `result` each as a variable.

What's noteworthy here is that if you already `totalsupply` being a valid dictionary, simply skip the `json.loads()` step above:

```
from operator import itemgetter
status, message, result = itemgetter('status', 'message', 'result')(totalsupply)

# alternatively if you have guarantees on the order:
status, message, result = totalsupply.values()
```

I would say, up until very recently, dicts in Python are unordered,  unpacking of d.values() may actually give you the wrong behavior. `OrderedDict` is not a thing until Python 3.6, and they're ordered by insertion. If this isn't something you understand yet, I would suggest sticking to the `itemgetter` solution.

Comment: wao I need a lot to learn thank you very much, pandas is for later  @onlyphantom

Comment: There no point in using a HTML parser here at all. The API returns just JSON. And using `itemgetter` just to get out 3 values is unnecessary. Also the order of items inside a JSON object is not guaranteed, so the `.values()` is not reliable.